# Dynamically iterate through multiple sheets while writing multiple dfs to excel using Excelwriter/xlsx writer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter, pandas.excelwriter

This is a sample code to write 2 dataframes in sheet `Result` for a workbook which works perfectly fine.I want to write various iterations of such dfs to multiple sheets generated dynamically.
How do I do it?

index sheet :-[index][1]

```
def write_dataframes_to_excel_sheet(dataframes, dir, name):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(f'{dir}/{name}.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        workbook = writer.book
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Result')
        writer.sheets['Result'] = worksheet

        COLUMN = 0
        row = 0

        for df in dataframes:
            worksheet.write_string(row, COLUMN, df.name)
            row += 1
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Result',
                        startrow=row, startcol=COLUMN)
            row += df.shape[0] + 2

# Create sample dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], columns=('A', 'B', 'C'))
df1.name = "Dataframe1"
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)], columns=('A', 'B', 'C'))
df2.name = "Dataframe2"
dataframes = [df1, df2]

write_dataframes_to_excel_sheet(dataframes, 'C:/Users/path', 'bar')

I tried this way it didn't work,prints 2 dfs one below the other only for the last most id
------------------------------------------------------------------------

    book = xlrd.open_workbook("input1.xlsx")
    first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Output1.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter')
    
    def write_dataframes_to_excel_sheet(dataframes, dir, name,writer):
        #with pd.ExcelWriter(f'{dir}/{name}.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        workbook = writer.book
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(str(id))
        writer.sheets[str(id)] = worksheet
    
        COLUMN = 0
        row = 0
    
        for df in dataframes:
            #worksheet.write_string(row, COLUMN, df.name)
            row += 1
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(id),
                        startrow=row, startcol=COLUMN)
            row += df.shape[0] + 2
    with pd.ExcelWriter('output1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    
        for i in [x for x in range(first_sheet.nrows) if x != 0]:
            id = int(first_sheet.cell(i,0).value)
            strt_row_num=1
            output_array= []
            for remarks_row in range(3,6):
            
                remarks = first_sheet.cell(i,remarks_row).value
                sql_query = '''select * from ( some query) '''.format(id)
                output = pd.DataFrame()
                for df in pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn, chunksize=10000):
                    output = output.append(df)  
                output.columns=output.columns.str.strip()
                output_array.append(output)
                #output_array=tuple(output_array)
                strt_row_num=strt_row_num +len(output) +3
        write_dataframes_to_excel_sheet(output_array, 'C:/Users/path','output1',writer)
            


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE5UO.png
```

Comment: Would you add the expected output?

Comment: what's the source of said sheets?

Comment: Its a index sheet with various sheet names(ID) in a column, Im reading from there and querying a df for each of those sheets(ID) and want to dynamically write for all the rows/sheet names in the index sheet. I cannot find any syntax or method online to dynamically write to different sheets( I do not understand how to go about iterating it)